# Fatal error: Call to a member function advanced_render() on a non-object

Tags: 7, views, theming

What I am doing wrong? The error says:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function advanced_render() on a
>   non-object in
>   /var/www/mydrupalsite/themes/myTheme/template.php
>   on line XXXX

```
/**
 * Overrides theme_views_view_field for a view
 *
 */
function myTheme_views_view_field($view, $field, $row) {
  //Work only for mobile view and section field
  if($view->name == 'mobile' && $field->options['label'] == 'Section') {
    $new_items = array();

    foreach($field->items as $skey => $subitem) {
      $new_items[$skey] = array();

      foreach($subitem as $key => $item) {
        $parent = taxonomy_get_parents($key);
        if(count($parent) == 0){
      //do not set item in items, if taxonomy does not have parent
        }
       else {
         $new_items[$skey][$key] = $item;
       }
      }
    }
  //Assign new items list to field items
    $field->items = $new_items;

    return $field->advanced_render($row);
  } else {
    return $field->advanced_render($row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have copied that code somewhat from a Drupal 6 version? The only problem is that the pattern for theme function signatures has changed in Drupal 7; only the `$vars` argument is passed in now, which is an array of named variables for the function:

```
function myTheme_views_view_field($vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $field = $vars['field'];
  $row = $vars['row'];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah Im in the process of upgrading Drupal 6 to 7